# bootstrap 4 not fully responsive with iphone 6

Tags: ios, css, bootstrap-4, iphone-6

[image: view]

When using my dev tools it shows perfectly for mobile but on my actual mobile my apps do not show correctly. Is this a bug with the iphone 6?

My meta tags

https://github.com/jwlindsey/jwlindsey.github.io

if you want to look at the index file or css. I am pretty sure I have it correct though.

Comment: wow, this showed horribly... Sorry I did such a poor job. I do not post very often.

Comment: your question needs to be self contained without any external links

Comment: though can have external links for reference

Comment: So I need to put code snipets in instead of a link to my code?

Comment: yes. Most ideal is a minimum reproducible snippet, for web stuff you can then also have a link to a pre setup https://jsbin.com   ( or any other sites dedicated to this kind of thing )

Answer (score 0):

Same problem encountered. 
I read their documentation https://getbootstrap.com 
**Browser support**
•   Dropped IE8, IE9, and iOS 6 support. v4 is now only IE10+ and iOS 7+. For sites needing either of those, use v3.
•   Added official support for Android v5.0 Lollipop’s Browser and WebView. Earlier versions of the Android Browser and WebView remain only unofficially supported.